# Interrupt Descriptor Table and System Call Table?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, interrupts, system-calls

Anyone please help me find out the relation between these two. Read somewhere that

> "The IDT is initialized one first time by the BIOS routine but Linux does it one more time when it take control."

So for interrupt hooking attacker have to change the contents again?

Whether the control is moved from IDT to System Call Table in a general sense, when a system call occurs?

Answer (score 0):

The [Interrupt Descriptor Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table) contains addresses of routines that are called by the hardware when an interrupt is raised in the computer.

The System Call Table is just a list of all the system calls for the operating system. This means the API. It normally has no physical existence, as it is just part of the documentation.